# mixed model specification in R (interactions and nesting)

Tags: r, regression, logistic, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I'm working with data from an experiment that I plan to analyze using a mixed-effects logistic model. In this study, 200 participants (identified by the variable Participant) were randomly assigned to one of four experimental conditions (variable: Condition). Within each condition, participants were tasked with determining whether a given word (variable: Word) could appropriately conclude a sentence (variable: Sentence).

We used a set of 30 unique words, and each participant had to evaluate all of them. For each word, participants were presented with two sentences: one where the word could correctly be used at the end (variable: Appropriateness = 'Yes') and another where it could not (variable: Appropriateness = 'No'). Participants earned a point (variable: score) for each correct judgment they made.

I would appreciate any advice on how to best approach the statistical analysis of this data using mixed-effects models.

Here's what I've been considering:

Model 1:

```
score ~ Condition * Appropriateness + (1|Participant) + (1|Word)
```

Model 2:

```
score ~ Condition * Appropriateness + (1|Participant) + (1|Sentence/Word)
```

Model 3:

```
score ~ Condition * Appropriateness + (Appropriateness|Participant) + 
                 (Appropriateness|Sentence/Word)
```

As you can see, my particular concern is related to specifying the random effects.

Please share your thoughts or suggestions on which model might be the most appropriate for this type of data.

Comment: Welcome RNewbie! Do I understand correctly that you had in all 60 sentences (2 for each word) and all were presented to each participant? Or were there sentences that were used for more than one word, like the "house is" + big, old, square, expensive? And you never used the same words with other sentences, e. g"my lover is"?

Comment: Yes, there were 60 sentences in total and they were all presented to each participant. Every sentence was used for a single word only

Comment: What exactly are you trying to find out?  Is it only whether the different conditions lead to different scores?

Comment: That's right @PeterFlom. I am interested in the effect of the four conditions on the score.  I also want to see how this effect is different depending on the appropriateness (= sentence type).

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean with "participants were tasked with determining whether a given word (variable: Word) could appropriately conclude a sentence (variable: Sentence)." What do you mean the words conclude a sentence?

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand I meant "appear at the end of a sentence". There was a gap at the end of every sentence. The participants' task was to decide whether each word could appropriately be inserted in that gap.

Comment: Isn't appropriateness fully confounded (i.e. collinear) with score? If you know appropriate (and word?) you know the score? (I'm not sure I understand your context tbh) Have you tried running at least the first model (which seems to be the best one--it's a so-called cross-classified model with random intercepts) and see what happens? Also FWIW I highly doubt model 3 is correct

Comment: @PatrickCoulombe Thank you for asking about Appropriateness. Let me clarify this. Approproateness is a property of a sentence, while Score is a property of a participant's response. These two are not collinear. Here is a simplistic example. For the word red, participants are given two sentences: 1. His face is (....) 2. He saw a (....). The Appropriateness values would be 1 and 0 respectively. Now, when a participant marks the first sentence as correct, their score value is 1. When they mark the second sentence as correct, their score value for that sentence is 0.

Comment: @PatrickCoulombe I've successfully fitted the first model and the results appear promising. However, I'm curious to know if the other two models are even better given the design of my study.

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment, I think model 1 is probably right. But you might not be able to estimate the random effect for word, and I think it would be OK to leave it out.

But I'm not certain of this. I await other answers.